How to handle button held down in WinAPI?
My program increments counter once if the button is depressed, but it does not increment continuously if the button is held down. How do I acheive that?
Here's a simple example code:
#include <Windows.h>

HINSTANCE g_hInst;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    static int n = 0;
    static HWND hEdit;
    static HWND hButton;

    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_CREATE:
        hEdit = CreateWindow(L"EDIT", L"0", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_CENTER | ES_READONLY, 100, 100, 100, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)1, g_hInst, NULL);
        hButton = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"▴", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_LEFT, 200 + 4, 100, 20, 20, hWnd, (HMENU)2, g_hInst, NULL);
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND: {
        HWND ctlHwnd = (HWND)lParam;
        int ctlId = LOWORD(wParam);
        int notificationCode = HIWORD(wParam);

        if (notificationCode == BN_CLICKED) {
            n++;
            wchar_t buf[40] = {0};
            wsprintf(buf, L"%d", n);
            SetWindowText(hEdit, buf);
        }
        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInst,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInst,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int iCmdShow)
{
    g_hInst = hInst;

    WNDCLASS wndClass = {
        .style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW,
        .lpfnWndProc = WindowProc,
        .hInstance = hInst,
        .hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION),
        .hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW),
        .hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(LTGRAY_BRUSH),
        .lpszMenuName = NULL,
        .lpszClassName = L"app",
    };
    if (!RegisterClass(&wndClass)) {
        OutputDebugString(L"Failed to register window class\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (!CreateWindow(
        L"app",
        L"Counter",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
        0, 0,
        1280, 720,
        NULL, NULL,
        hInst, NULL))
    {
        OutputDebugString(L"Failed to create window\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    MSG msg = {};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}


You can check if the button is held down via the BM_GETSTATE message.

Start the timer (see SetTimer) when the button is pressed. The button itself isn't going to send any more notifications while held.

@IgorTandetnik: Ok, what next? what do I do on WM_TIMER?

Well, you increment the counter, or whatever it is you wanted to be done continuously while the button is held.

... and KillTimer() when the button is released. Mind you, this is a fair bit more complex than it appears: When a button is pressed with the mouse it captures mouse input. With the mouse button still pressed you can now move the mouse cursor outside the button and back in and the button will change states. You're going to have to determine how your program should respond to this.

Also, note that WM_TIMER messages are very low priority. Input messages have higher priority meaning that for as long as you're generating input (e.g., by moving the mouse), no timer messages are generated by the system. That's usually not an issue in practice but worth keeping in mind.

Try subclassing the button to handle its WM_LBUTTON(DOWN|UP) messages, or have your parent window handle BN_(UN)PUSHED notifications from the button.
